# Microsoft.VBE reference in .NET 5.0 not available

Tags: c#, .net

When I type the following in a .NET 5.0 project:

```
Microsoft.
```

The following options show up:

[image]

But in .NET Framework:

[image]

The `VBE` option is available.

Why is this the case? How do I get the `VBE` to show up in my .NET 5.0 project?

Comment: Is VBE available in .netcore ?

Comment: @Neil Got it working now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I did was:

- Opened both projects.
- Opened up Reference Manager for both projects.
- Searched `Microsoft`
- Compared the 2 projects, which referenced were used.
- And, the one I needed was `Microsoft Visual Basis for Applications Extensibility 5.3`.
- Cleaned & Rebuild the project.